# Grails GORM integer validation

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Environment: Grails 2.0.4, Java 1.6.0

I'd like to put a constraint on a Domain Object value requiring an integer value to prevent a decimal value from being entered. Entering 3.3 in the view results in the object being created with a value of 3. I was hoping for a validation error that would be kicked back to the user indicating only integer values are valid.

```
class ADomainObject {
    Integer    anInteger
}
```

Controller

```
def save() {
   // Note: params["anInteger"] = "3.3"

   ADomainObject aDomainObject = new ADomainObject(params)
   aDomainObject.save flush:true
}
```

Result in the persistence of aDomainObject.anInteger = 3

What type of constraint would be needed to cause a failure? I've tried using a range constraint, [0..1000], to no avail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can register a custom property editor for `Integers` to only allow strictly Integer values. The following will apply to binding all Integers.

```
class IntegerEditor extends java.beans.PropertyEditorSupport {
    void setAsText(String text) {
        value = Integer.parseInt(text)
    }
}

class CustomPropertyEditorRegistrar implements org.springframework.beans.PropertyEditorRegistrar {
    void registerCustomEditors(org.springframework.beans.PropertyEditorRegistry registry) {
        registry.registerCustomEditor(Integer, new IntegerEditor())
    }
}
```

and then in resources.groovy:

```
beans = {
    customPropertyEditorRegistrar(CustomPropertyEditorRegistrar)
}
```

Comment: will this throw a validation error? because I think it will throw a type mismatch error before even validating anything

Comment: This will propagate up to a validation error. `setAsText()` can throw an `IllegalArgumentException`, which the `NumberFormatException` thrown by `parseInt()` extends. An exception being thrown is interpreted as a validation error by Spring.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Am I off base expecting this to be the default behavior? Is there a reason it is not the default behavior that I'm missing?

Comment: This works great, the only problem is that if I use this approach I no longer have the incorrect value to place back in the form that the cmd object was backing. Any ideas on how to get the invalid value back to the UI for display in the input field?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a custom validator like this:

```
static constraints = {
        anInteger validator: {
            //aDomainObject. anInteger.invalid.type
            if (!(it instanceOf Integer)) return ['invalid.type']
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't think that will work because the value will have already been bound to the Integer field at this point.