# Matching last character of string fails

Tags: regex, grails, groovy

I cannot understand why this very simple regex is failling:

```
"3243" ==~ /^\d+$/
```

I want val to only be a string of numbers. The following return true:

```
"213213" ==~ /^\d+/ 
"213213dsadasd" ==~ /^\d+/
```

These are part of a field validation in a domain object. This is the complete code:

```
    static constraints = {
       intValue validator: {val,obj ->

        if(val){
            "${val}" ==~ /^[0-9]*$/ 
        }     
       }
    }
```

The above example will accept "321a31" or "321aa"... Not sure if the regex is wrong or something else is off...

intValue is an Integer, although the default validation would accept strings like '32112dsa'(and only store the numeric part) thats why I am trying to create a custom validator.

Comment: Skipped a beat there. Yes typo.

Comment: What version of groovy?

Comment: jdk 7 and grails 2.3.11

Comment: It looks like `==~` requires a strict match, what will happen of you remove anchors? `"3243" ==~ /\d+/ `?

Comment: I can have letters in there then which I dont want. The first anchor `^` is working. Its the last one and mix letters that fail.

Comment: ~ /\d+/ will only fail if there are no numbers at all.

Comment: `/^\d+$/` works here in Groovy 2.1.9 (which I believe is the version bundled with Grails 2.3.11) and Groovy 2.4.3...

Comment: Couldn't find what's causing the issues, but I would try aditional regexes that essentially do the same. `^(?=\d*$).*` etc. Not sure how likely that is to work, but might give some extra info at some point.

Comment: @andrisleduskrasts could you replicate this? I will test more regex soon.

Comment: @Giannis Can't test right now, i read some documentations but couldn't find anything specific that could cause this.

Comment: @Giannis your regex with groovy 2.4.3 and java 1.7.0.71 works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the regex was not making any difference is that the values reaching the domain object field were already parsed automatically. A workaround for this can be found on this answer: [Grails GORM integer validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12681441/grails-gorm-integer-validation)